# How to: Nested Lists in SQLite-Net Extensions

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net-extensions

**How to: Do nested lists in sqlite-net-extensions**
Answer Found: Keeping the question as an example of how to do it.
The problem i encountered was not sqlite-net-extensions related, but i'm keeping the question for context.

**[Old Question]**
*I've got a problem with TwinCoders SQLite-net extensions.

I'm trying to insert a Series object into my database:*

*I'm using the `Db.InsertWithChildren(SelectedSeriesObject,recursive:true)` method.

The Series object is added accordingly with it's attributes.

All the Episodes are added as well, no problems there.*

*The problem is the BaseSeason.

It will only insert one Season object, which is (for some reason) the last Season Object of the list of Seasons in the Series*

```
public class BaseSeries : BaseMedia
{
[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Indexed]
public int ShowId { get; set; }

public string FirstAirDate { get; set; }
public string LastAirDate { get; set; }
public string Status { get; set; }

[OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
public List<BaseSeason> Seasons { get; set; }
/// <summary>
/// TvShow = 0, Anime = 1
/// </summary>
public int SeriesType { get; set; }

}

public class BaseSeason
{
[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
public int Id { get; set; }

[ForeignKey(typeof(BaseSeries))]
public int SeasonId { get; set; }

public int SeasonNumber { get; set; }
public int NumberOfEpisodes { get; set; }
public string Plot { get; set; }
public string Poster { get; set; }
public string AirDate { get; set; }

[OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
public List<BaseEpisode> Episodes { get; set; }    
[ManyToOne]
public BaseSeries BaseSeries { get; set; }

}

public class BaseEpisode
{
[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
public int Id { get; set; }

[ForeignKey(typeof(BaseSeason))]
public int EpisodeId { get; set; }

public string Title { get; set; }
public string Plot { get; set; }
public string Poster { get; set; } //still path
public string AirDate { get; set; }
public int EpisodeNumber { get; set; }
public int SeasonNumber { get; set; }
public string SeriesName { get; set; }    

[ManyToOne]
public BaseSeason BaseSeason { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anyone with experience regarding nested relationships in sqlite-net-extensions that knows how to make this work or see what i did wrong?

[image: Intended Relation]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***So regarding writing nested lists in sqlite-net-extensions:***

My problem turned out the be related to how I handle the creation of these objects, this is by no means related to sqlite-net extensions. So my bad!

Which means that the questions example is valid and works. (I tested it of course)

- **Setting up the entities for the database:**
  The example shown in my question, with a Series class, Season class and Episode class, is the correct way of setting it up.
- **Inserting into the database:**
  If you're wondering how to insert an object similar to my Series object (with nested lists), use:
  `db.InsertWitchChildren(yourObject, recursion: true)`
  Here's an extended example:

  ```
  public void AddSeries()
  {            
      MediaDB.db.CreateTable<BaseSeries>();
      MediaDB.db.CreateTable<BaseSeason>();
      MediaDB.db.CreateTable<BaseEpisode>();

      MediaDB.db.InsertWithChildren(SelectedSeries, recursion: true);            
  }
  ```

**Side Note:**
The example uses a static property on class with the connection string. Like so:

```
    public class MediaDB
    {
        public static SQLiteConnection db => new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformGeneric(),"Media.db");
    }
```

**Refrain from doing this** it is not really the best thing to do, since you should use `using` for the SQLiteConnection, making sure it's disposed once you're done with it.

more info on: [sqlite-net-extentions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions)

**[UPDATE]: Further expansion of handling nested lists in sqlite-net extensions:**

- **Deleting tables with children:**
  This is quite simple, but i spent a good hour and half figuring it out anyways.
  Just use:
  For lists/arrays: `db.DeleteAll(yourCollection, recursion: true)`
  For single objects: `db.Delete(yourObject, true);`
  As an exmaple: here's my implementation of a method that will delete a List
  (BaseSeries is the class shown in the original question question):

  ```
  public static void RemoveCollection<T>(List<T> collection)
  {
      using (db)
      {
          if (typeof(T) == typeof(BaseMovie))
          {
              db.DeleteAll(collection);
          }

          if (typeof(T) == typeof(BaseSeries))
          {
              db.DeleteAll(collection, recursion: true);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  The BaseMovie class is a simple single entity, recursion is not needed since it holds no children.

Comment: Generic Repository RemoveCollection() needing knowledge of specialized Model classes, and their internal structure, seems counter intuitive.